# Best hidden device for sound recording outdoor interviews

Tags: microphone, voice, interviews, outdoor, outdoors

Hello sound enthusiasts!

I have been looking for a good sound recording device to use outside for interviewing people. I do want it to be hidden, so that it's invisible to the person I'm interviewing.

I have also bought and used lavalier (lapel) microphones, but all those damn wires are such a hassle to hide and microphone itself is easily visible under my T-Shirt. Tried taping it, but again, it takes so much effort and time to set it up.

I just want to connect my mic to my phone and don't have to plug unplug any wires or put any wires around me under my clothes.

Is there something that is completely wireless, not noticeable if you are in a white T-Shirt and that records the voice of both me and a person I interview?

I was looking at wireless earbuds the other day that have sound recording capability, but they all seem to be made for calls, which means I would hear myself but not the person I'm interviewing.

Comment: Whatever you use, you are subject to the inverse square law, meaning you are going to be 10 times louder than whoever you're talking to simply due to relative distances. I'd also watch out for this even being legal in your jurisdiction. Unless you could claim in court this is "in the public interest" you could be liable.

Comment: Hey @Tetsujin thank you for the input! I always reveal that I'm recording after the interview and ask if they are fine with me using the recording. Despite the inverse square law, any ideas what would be the best option I could get?

Comment: You need a shotgun mic, though I don't know of any small enough to hide. If a lav mic is too much hassle, a shotgun will triple that logistically. You can, btw, get radio gear for any of this so you can do away with a lot of the wires - though I think your entry-level starts at about 4 grand;))